Unknown Entity annotated with @MappedSuperclass
I have parent class
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommonDate extends HibernatePersistentObject implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "INSTRUMENT_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
private InstrumentUsage instrumentUsage;

it doesn't have @Id because it's just parent class with additional parameters, it won't write to any table.
Another class which is extending CommonDate is:
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBSERVATION_DATES")
public class ObservationDate extends CommonDate {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DATES_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DATES_SEQ", sequenceName = "DATES_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "OBSERVATION_DATE_ID")
    private int ObservationDateId;

public ObservationDate(InstrumentUsage instrumentUsage) {
        super(instrumentUsage);
    }

    public ObservationDate() {
        super();
    }

This one is class which I would like to write into database, into OBSERVATION_DATES table.
And there is third class in constructor: InstrumentUsage.
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class InstrumentUsage extends HibernatePersistentObject implements Serializable {

also without @Id but annotated with @MappedSuperclass and error which I get is:
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on domain.ObservationDate.instrumentUsage references an unknown entity: domain.InstrumentUsage
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1808)

Can't I access InstrumentUsage with @ManyToOne because it's not @Entity?

The issue arises because InstrumentUsage is not considered an entity by Hibernate and does not map to a table in the database. Consequently, you cannot use @ManyToOne or @OneToOne relationships to reference it since those annotations require the target class to be a managed entity (@Entity).
If you need to include the instrumentUsage field in CommonDate, consider modifying your inheritance strategy. Instead of @MappedSuperclass, you can use one of the following approaches to define a proper database relationship:

Single Table Strategy: This maps all classes in the hierarchy to a single database table. It’s simple and performant but can lead to sparsely populated tables if your subclasses have distinct fields.

Joined Table Strategy: This maps each subclass to its own table with a shared primary key. It maintains normalized data structures but can result in more complex queries.


You can learn more about these strategies and how to implement them here: Hibernate Inheritance Strategies.
By choosing one of these strategies, you can turn InstrumentUsage into an entity (@Entity) and establish the required relationship in CommonDate.
